# Try to send post data to a nodejs server

Tags: java, node.js, json

here is for several days I block on a proleme. I have to send a post request with json data to a server and I try this:

```
 private void sendRequestInfo() {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("email", "test@gmail.com");
        json.put("password", "abcd");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    resultOne.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            resultOne.setText(error.toString());
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

communication with the server seems to be done since node brings out this line:

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `services`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'register@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;

but I have this error:

**"Value Logged of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"**

normally the node server should send me back "user not found" I do not understand this error if someone can help me.

Comment: Did you missed the header Content-Type or any authetication in POSTMan?

Comment: This command works : curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"email":"test@gmail.com", "password":"abcd"}' http://localhost:8080/login, 
how do i add in my code "content type"?

Comment: You have to write in your code...........               <?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root><foo a="b">Tada</foo></root>';
?>

Comment: the problem is not the server but the java code in my application :/